# store polish characters mysql

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8

I am trying to save characters like "ą", "ć", "ł" but they are saved in the database as question marks (I save them using phpMyAdmin).

The database and table's collation is utf8_bin.

Comment: Did you set the connection to UTF-8? (via `SET NAMES utf8;` as first statement)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try changing the collation to:

```
utf8_unicode_ci
```

or

```
utf8_polish_ci
```

You can refer to: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll

Also you can TRY altering the specific column with:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN txt TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Comment: You can try to ALTER the column you store the specific data: `ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN txt TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8`

Answer (score 2):

I've searched a lot and finally, I got a solution with this:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName MODIFY COLUMN columnName VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET `binary`;
```

You can change `VARCHAR(64)` to match your needs. I hope this helps someone. **Note that I did not only required to store Polish characters but French and Spanish ones as well.** So the solutions above might work for just polish chars.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change column from vchar to nvchar. Then when inserting values to DB remember to ad N before as follows: N'ŁÓDŹ' (in persistence frameworks u should have some kind of NString representation)

from documentation:

> Nvarchar stores UNICODE data. If you have requirements to store UNICODE or multilingual data, nvarchar is the choice. Varchar stores ASCII data and should be your data type of choice for normal use. Regarding memory usage, nvarchar uses 2 bytes per character, whereas varchar uses 1

Comment: This information seems to be related to Transact-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server), not MySQL.