# Mysql does not display Polish characters

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

my mysql does not display Polish characters and I created the database like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [store polish characters mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547046/store-polish-characters-mysql)

Comment: I trying utf8_unicode_ci  but not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the side of entity-framework, because I called it using the Seed method from Migration, when everything is added using the controller everything is ok, I tried to insert SQL into ordinary SQL and it worked

This not working:

```
   protected override void Seed(WebApplication2.Context context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.

        context.Persons.Add(new Person { Age = 19, LastName = "ćżół", Name = "Sławek" });

 });

    }
```